# Using mqtt paho for Python in a raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to connect to message broker using python 2.7 in raspbian as follows:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho


host="messagesight.demos.ibm.com"
port=1883

def on_connect(pahoClient, obj, rc):
# Once connected, publish message
        print "Connected Code = %d"%(rc)
        client.publish("prueba/123", "Hello World", 0)


def on_log(pahoClient, obj, level, string):
        print string

def on_publish(pahoClient, packet, mid):
# Once published, disconnect
        print "Published"
        pahoClient.disconnect()

def on_disconnect(pahoClient, obj, rc):
        print "Disconnected"

# Create a client instance
client=paho.Client()

# Register callbacks
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_log = on_log
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.on_disconnnect = on_disconnect

#Set userid and password
client.username_pw_set(userID, password)

#connect
x = client.connect(host, port, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

When I run the script, Im getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ejemplo.py", line 27, in
>   
>       client=paho.Client()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   410, in **init**
>       self._sockpairR, self._sockpairW = _socketpair_compat()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   255, in _socketpair_compat
>       listensock.bind(("localhost", 0))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

How can I fix it?

Comment: Feels a bit odd writing this, but do you have IPv4 support on your Pi?

Comment: Or perhaps your "lo" interface is down. Try `ifconfig lo down; ifconfig lo up`

Answer (score 1):

I just quickly tired your code and it is publishing to `messagesight.demos.ibm.com` fine.

[image: example]

The only thing I did was comment out the userID, password.

```
#client.username_pw_set(userID, password)
```

Have you installed Paho Python Client correctly, also good example there as well. http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/

Comment: yes, Paho Python client is correctly installed... it is still not working. We are still getting the same issue " cannot assing requested address". Which is the content of your client.py file? Can you locate line 260 "listensock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 0))"? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the output of
`ifconfig -a`

Comment: @maria sounds like what the other guys are mentioning , chi network config.

Comment: thanks, you are right! The problem was the /etc/network/interfaces file, it was not configured properly ...

Comment: For other people, what @MariaBorbones and @Matt was referring to was the comment on the question. The problem is that `lo` or loopback interface is down. you can enable it using `sudo ifconfig lo up`